# Payment Gateway Implementation

Tags: php, mysql, payment-gateway

I am integrating one of the payment gateway to my site in PHP, Before proceeding further, As I am new to this, I have some doubts (use cases/scenarios), So I need a solution to deal with these scenarios. I have listed them here

**1)**  How to pass unique id to payment gateway, while It considers it as a Order No, But In real scenario  Order NO/ID will be generated only on successful transaction. I thought of sending a random number to Payment gateway. On successful transaction i can store in Order table.

**Table: Order**

1) aID:(unique, Primary, AI)

2) RandomNo(unique)

3) Order Date

Is this a good Idea

**2)** Which ID to be shown to user As **ORDER ID** either the **aID or RandomNO**

**3)** Do I need to store the Response from the payment gateway in the DB, such as Payment ID(unique), Response Code, OrderNO & Amount. How it will be useful.

**4)** What are the possible scenarios that can occur after payment gateway integration, And How to deal them

Comment: Usually payment gateways will have documentation that answers all of these questions, or possibly even PHP libraries that do most of the hard grunt for you.  Have you read their manual?

Answer (score 6):

1) How to pass unique id to payment gateway, while It considers it as a Order No, But In real scenario Order NO/ID will be generated only on successful transaction. I thought of sending a random number to Payment gateway. On successful transaction i can store in Order table.

**ANS** : First of all insert the order in database before redirecting to payment gateway and use the unique id of that insertion as order id.

2) Which ID to be shown to user As ORDER ID either the aID or RandomNO

**ANS** : The order id as mentioned above can be shown to the user.

3) Do I need to store the Response from the payment gateway in the DB, such as Payment ID(unique), Response Code, OrderNO & Amount. How it will be useful.

**ANS** : Yes! You must store response from payment gateway as you may need it in future in case of any dispute.

4) What are the possible scenarios that can occur after payment gateway integration, And How to deal them

**ANS** : I didn't get you in this question.

Comment: Storing the data before redirecting to payment gateway can create junk rows in DB, If user goes back or On unsuccessful transaction the inserted row will be a junk, that is a needless entry to the DB

Comment: @Vinay If you don't store data in DB before redirecting, you may loose the order data if payment gateway fails to process your order.

Comment: I will be storing the data in session, even transaction fails, the data will be in session, Unless user clears the session, Actually i am asking user to perform the transaction again on transaction failure, but on successful transaction, i store the session data to DB. So why to store the data to DB before redirection.